# How do I ask for a full diff of a branch in git?

Tags: git

My goal is to get the whole diff of the whole branch in git. Provided my branch is named `foo/bar`, what's the appropriate command (i.e. args to `git diff`, I assume) to see the whole diff? (this branch received many different merges from other branches).

**Edit**: Perhaps I was not so clear with the requirement of *whole branch diff*, but what I meant is taking two commits:

1. The last commit of a branch.
2. The parent commit of a branch.

I need those two arguments to be passed to a `git diff` command. Is there a -shortcut- way to specify both commits?

Comment: `git diff branch^..branch`

Comment: That command compares the current branch status against the status when the branch started?

Comment: everything since foo/bar split from master is `git diff master...foo/bar`.  If you're after everything since your current branch split from its upstream it's `git diff @{upstream}...` or `git diff @{u}...`.  Note the three dots, that's "since the merge base" and it's specific to diff, since yours is a very common request.

Comment: There's no such thing as when a branch "starts", given the Git model itself (discounting root commits). That command compares the branch pointer to the parent of the branch pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### diff ... as compared to what?

There is no such thing as a "diff of a branch".  There are only diffs of commits.<sup>1</sup>  Pick *any two* commits and you can compare them.  But a branch ... well, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  A branch is not two commits.  A branch *name* can select *one* commit, or you can use a branch name in conjunction with something else to select *many* commits.  But one commit is not enough, and many commits is too many.  You must pick exactly *two* commits.

Note that `git diff branch1 branch2` and `git diff branch1..branch2` mean *exactly the same thing:* translate the name `branch1` to one specific commit, and translate the name `branch2` to one specific commit, and then diff those two specific commits.  Again, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also diff a commit against your work-tree, or against your index; and you can diff your index against your work-tree.  Besides these, there are specialized forms of diffs to look at just one file, even one outside a Git repository; and you can have Git compute several different diffs, then combine them into a single *combined diff*.  The combined diff, however, is designed to be used only with merge commits, and diffs the final merged result against each parent.  It's not useful for viewing many arbitrary commits, only for checking the final result of a merge.

---

#### After the edit

You may be able to get what you want—but there isn't really a "parent commit of the branch" either.  Consider, for instance, this graph fragment:

```
...--o--A--o--o--o    <-- br1
         \
          o--B--o     <-- br2
              \
               o--o   <-- feature
```

The newest commit of each branch is the right-most `o`, and each commit connects back to an earlier parent commit.  (These connections are stored internally as those big ugly SHA-1 hash IDs, with each commit saving its parent IDs.  Parents don't know their children, because the children don't exist yet when the parents are made, and once made, no commit can ever be changed.  So the children know their parents, but not vice versa.)

What is the "parent" commit of `feature`?  Is it commit `A` or commit `B`?  (It's probably *not* any of the remaining commits, which is why I only gave specific one-letter names to those two.)  Or:

```
...--A--o--o--B--o--C--o    <-- devel
      \      /     /
       o----o--o--D--E--F   <-- feat
```

Here `feat` has been repeatedly brought into `devel`, at points `B` and `C`.  It can be brought in again; if so, that will introduce the changes from `E` and `F` with respect to `D`.  But it seems obvious from this graph drawing that `feat` originally "grew out of" commit `A`, so is `A` the parent you want, or is it more related to `B` or `C`?  If it's not `C`, you will have a problem, because Git doesn't record `A` or `B` independently anywhere (it doesn't record `C` independently either but we have an easy way to *find*, well, not `C` but `D`; but `D` is perhaps what you want).  Moreover, while it *seems* obvious that `A` is the starting point, that's merely because of the way I drew this graph fragment.  A different view might make it equally clear that there is an earlier starting point—and in fact, there just isn't a real "starting point" unless you specifically record one (tags are ideal for this purpose).

#### Merge bases: how to find `A` or `B` in the first diagram and `D` in the second

Git supports—because it must, because `git merge` needs it—the concept of a *merge base*.  The merge base of two commits is easy(ish) to see if you draw a graph of the commits like we did above.  The commits are usually two different branch tip commits (and if not, we just *pretend* they are).  You simply start at each tip, then follow its the connecting lines leftwards / backwards.  Eventually, this needs to "meet up" at some *common* commit.  That's the first commit that's on *both* of these branches, and that commit is the *merge base*.

Here's that first diagram again:

```
...--o--A--o--o--o    <-- br1
         \
          o--B--o     <-- br2
              \
               o--o   <-- feature
```

Starting at the tip of `feature` *and* the tip of `br1`, check to see if you have a common commit yet.  No—so look back a bit.  Looking back on `br1` there's a point where something comes in, at commit `A`.  Can we get to commit `A` from `feature`?  Yes: we start at the tip of `feature` and go back two steps to `B`, then go back two more steps to `A`.  That's the first shared commit—the first commit that's on *both* `br1` *and* `feature`.  So that's the merge base.

The merge base of `br1` and `br2` is likewise commit `A`, and the merge base of `br2` and `feature` is commit `B`.  Hence, given two branch names—or even just two commit IDs—we can find their merge base.

The merge base for the second diagram is trickier.  Commit `C` is a *merge commit*.  This means it has two parent arrows, one to a commit that is only on branch `devel`, and one to commit `D` on `feat`.  (Note, by the way, that this means we made commit `D` *before* we made commit `C`.  The graph lettering here is a bit misleading!  Sorry about that.)  This makes commit `D` *reachable* from the tip of `devel`, so that commit `D` is on both branches—and that, plus its "most close"-ness to the branch tips, makes commit `D` the merge base of `devel` and `feat`.

#### `git merge-base`

The command `git merge-base A B` will find the merge base of the two named branches.  Ideally, this will be a single commit ID.  (It could be *no* ID, if the two branches literally have nothing in common—they have unrelated histories; this is rare—or there could be more than one merge base, in which case `git merge-base` just picks one, somewhat arbitrarily.  It's hard to get multiple merge bases, though, so generally you don't have to worry about this.)

Hence, if the goal at this point is to find commit `D` in the second diagram, and diff that against the tip of `feat`, you can do:

```
git merge-base devel feat    # and note the commit ID
git diff <hash> feat
```

Because this is a relatively common thing to *want*, `git diff` has it built in.  The syntax for this borrows the three-dot syntax that for *every other* Git command means something else:

```
git diff devel...feat
```

Note the three (not two) dots between the two names.  For `git diff`, and *only* for `git diff`, this means "find the merge base between these two branch tip commits, and then diff it against the second commit."

With the first diagram, you can pick `br1` or `br2` to find either `A` or `B` and compare that to the tip of `feature`:

```
git diff br1...feature
```

for instance.

Comment: Edited the question: I'd like to compare the current status of my branch against the parent commit (i.e. the status where I created the branch from)

Answer (score 2):

Simply `git diff commit_hash1 commit_hash2`

where `commit_hash1` is the hash of the parent of the first commit on your branch (note that it is not part of your branch), and `commit_hash2` is the head of your branch (the commit that your branch is currently pointing to).

Comment: I am struggling to find such parent. This branch is insanely long, against good practices xD.